# how to use long working function in aiogram without blocking?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, blocking, aiogram

I am writing a bot in aiogram and I want to use a function from a third-party library. The function `fun()` works for a very long time, and blocks the execution of the entire code (while it is being executed, the bot cannot respond to other users). It is impossible to rewrite this library into asynchronous code. How do I make that the function does not block all the code?

```
import ...
import example_library
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


async def on_startup(_):
    print("bot is online")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)
    await example_library.fun(*args, **kwargs) ### block function, works for a long time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: threading would work:   https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html  or multiprocessing    https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I expected, everything is done in one line:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)
    await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, example_library.fun, *args, **kwargs)
```